# Android life cycle of an object in a listview, arraylist and arrayadapter

Tags: arrays, android-listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm building a prototype app that helps researchers track a small cohort (8-10) of subject patients. They need to periodically update the patient information.  I want to be able to touch a button to bring up a listview of all patients with much if not all of the patient info in each row. I created a basic class of Patient:

```
public class Patient {

 public String name;
public String gender;
public int painLevel;
public String risk;
public int score;

public Patient() {
    super();
}

public Patient(String name, String gender, int painLevel, String risk,
        int score) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.location = painLevel;
    this.risk = risk;
    this.score = score;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public int getpainLevel() {
    return painLevel;
}

public void setpainLevel(int painLevel) {
    this.painLevel = painLevel;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public void setRisk(String risk) {
    this.risk = risk;
}

public String getRisk() {
    return risk;
}
```

}

Initially I entered them into an array in this way:

```
 Patient[] cohort= new Patient[maxPatients];
```

Now I find that in order to display in a ListView I must use an arrayadapter.  I've found numerous examples and tutorials such as [Vogella's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial that helped very much.  Unfortunately, most examples use string arrays to make the example.

I've been able to put my list up with all the info I need. Now I need to use a popup dialog after a longpress that selects an individual patient for showing/editing all the data. I've been able to do this, but here is where I get stuck.

I can edit the data and it appears to change the Patient fields in the arrayList and arrayadapter. What I need help with is how to reflect those changes in the original array cohort[] of patients and also deleting a patient in the cohort. Right now it deletes a patient but does not remove it from the list on the screen until I change orientation even though I call notifyDataSetChanged();.

As a novice android programmer, I obviously don't fully understand the relationship between the original array, the array list, the array adapter - even after all the reading I've done. My current code is clumsy and not very elegant because it is cobbled together from bits and pieces of many of the examples out there plus lots of unnecessary debug code. During debug, I see multiple copies of the patients in the cohort array, the arraylist and arrayadapter.

I currently launch an edit screen if a user hits the 'Edit Patients' button using a new intent. The array of patients is used to build the arraylist in an arrayadapter and the list appears on the screen. A longpress brings up a specific patient using an alert dialog that has edit capabilities then 'save', Delete', and Cancel buttons.

I need to start over but need some guidance from more experienced programmers on how to approach this better. Pointers to basic working example code is sufficient or possibly a flow chart on the life cycle of an object in a listview would be even better. (I tried to make one but got most humbly lost.) I also spent hours on developer.android.com but lose track of my original quest following all the related links.

I need the app to run on Android 2.3 and up because Grad school researchers don't all have the latest android gear. Hopefully that makes no difference in the approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, most examples use string arrays to make the example.

My example below is a minimal example on how you can create your own adapter, then use an arraylist of patients in the listview.

I have done something simlar, just another class in the list. 
If you create an arraylist of the patients:

```
ArrayList <Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
// Add patients to the list:
patientList.add(new Patient());
patientList.add(new Patient());
// etc...
```

Then add your custom adapter to the listview.

```
PatientListAdapter adapter = new PatientListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), patientList);
ListView patientListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create your custom list adapter:

```
private class PatientListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;

    private final ArrayList<Patient> patientList;

    public PatientListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Patient> itemsArrayList) {

       this.context = context;
       patientList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // code below
    }
}
```

Then you need to override the getView function of the custom adapter. Then inside the getView, you can access a Patient inside the arraylist:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // This is a veeery minimal example.

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Custom layout for a row if you want to:
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_row, parent, false);

   // get the patient's name from the list of patients:

    (TextView) name = (TextView) covertView.findViewById(R.id.patient_name);
    String patientName = patientList.get(position).getName();
    name.setText = patientName;

  return convertView;
}
```

At last, I encourage you to implement the ViewHolder Pattern to increase performance in your ListView.